# Прописная или строчная "двадцатка" (G20)?

Tags: орфография, ономастика, прописная-строчная

"Большая двадцатка" как неофициальное название Группы двадцати (G20) пишется в кавычках, поскольку это условное наименование, первое слово с прописной. А как писать сокращенный вариант — **"двадцатка"** — с прописной или строчной?

Answer (score 2):

С прописной, как имя собственное. В сокращённом варианте.

См. текст из Вики:

> G6 возникла на совещании глав государств и правительств Франции, США,
>   Великобритании, ФРГ, Италии и Японии во дворце Рамбуйе 15—17 ноября
>   1975 (с начала 70-х годов подобные встречи проводились на уровне
>   министров финансов). В 1976 году «шестёрка» превратилась в «семёрку»,
>   приняв в свой состав Канаду, а в течение 1991—2002 поэтапно (по схеме
>   «7+1») была преобразована в «восьмёрку» с участием России. С 2014 года
>   вновь функционирует в формате «семёрки» — после присоединения Крыма к
>   РФ западные страны отказались участвовать в работе G8 и стали
>   проводить встречи в формате G7.

Здесь все закавыченные цифры - со строчной, но упоминаются они не как названия, а как "поэтапное" нарастание числительных.

---

Лирическое дополнение.

Полистала Интернет. Выяснилось, что и двадцатка и прецеденты не имеют устойчивого написания (см. "Большая восьмёрка" - Большая Восьмёрка - "большая восьмёрка"...

Напрашивается вывод: если название группы закавычено, пишите как бог на душу положит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Термин "двадцатка" обычно используется в текстах, **где уже использовались другие названия Группы двадцати, например "Большая двадцатка".** Тогда название пишется со строчной буквы и заключается в кавычки.

Пример: Шестой саммит G20 прошел 3-4 ноября 2011 года во французском Канне.
В ходе встречи лидеры **"двадцатки"** рассмотрели состояние мировой экономики и  реформирование мировой валютно-финансовой системы . ["Группа двадцати" (G20): состав, цели и хроника встреч | ria.ru](https://ria.ru/spravka/20130904/960495560.html)